# Only one out of two simple JS function executing onclick

Tags: javascript, function, class, onclick

Currently writing JavaScript for a simple webpage containing 3 types of recipes: starters, main courses and desserts. On clicking the starters button, all main courses and desserts hsould be hidden

I have 'tagged' certain elements on the page by giving them a class name and have written the following code:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="startersOnly()" >starter</a></li>

<script> 
function hideDesserts(){
    var desserts = document.querySelectorAll('.dessert');
    for (x in desserts) {
    desserts[x].style.display='none';
    }   
}
function hideMainCourse() {
    var maincourse = document.querySelectorAll('.main_course');
    for (y in maincourse) {
    maincourse[y].style.display='none';
    }
}
function startersOnly() {
    hideMainCourse();
    hideDesserts();
                }
</script>
```

Only hideMainCourse() is executing.
When I reverse the order only hideDesserts() executes.

Error Message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
    at hideMainCourse (portfolio.html:99)
    at startersOnly (portfolio.html:103)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM401 portfolio.html:84)
hideMainCourse @ portfolio.html:99
startersOnly @ portfolio.html:103
onclick @ VM401 portfolio.html:84
```

Comment: Is there any error message in the console?

Comment: As follows, I'm fairly new to Web Dev so I barely understand a thing:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
    at hideMainCourse (portfolio.html:99)
    at startersOnly (portfolio.html:103)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM401 portfolio.html:84)
hideMainCourse @ portfolio.html:99
startersOnly @ portfolio.html:103
onclick @ VM401 portfolio.html:84

Comment: I have provided a working example below using forEach loop which does what you desire. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your second function is not called is because the first one throws an exception. When an exception is thrown, the normal flow of control is interrupted, so the `startersOnly` function will not complete. You will need to fix the bug in your other two functions which is causing this exception.

I suspect the bug is caused because [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a NodeList, which you can iterate over using

```js
for(var x of desserts) {
    x.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Iterating over a sequence using `for(x in sequence)` will not work; this kind of loop iterates over an object, not a sequence. Note the difference between `of` and `in`.

Answer (score 0):

`hideMainCourse` functions throws an error and that's why second function `hideDesserts` is not running.

Here's updated code to resolve your error.

```
function hideDesserts(){
    try {
        var desserts = document.querySelectorAll('.dessert');
        for (x of desserts) {
            x.style.display='none';
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    } 
}

function hideMainCourse() {
    try {
        var maincourse = document.querySelectorAll('.main_course');
        for (var y of maincourse) {
            y.style.display='none';
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The console log already shows an exception with a stack trace, so it won't really help to log the exceptions because they're already visible in the console.

Comment: @kaya3, `console.log` is necessary when using `try/catch` for a stack trace. And the updated code is not only `try/catch`.

Comment: No, that is not true. The OP already has a stack trace in the console without writing `console.log` anywhere. Adding `try/catch` doesn't improve the code or make it easier to debug.

Comment: Even first function has an error, second function will be run if first function uses try catch. That's why try catch is added.

Comment: The solution is to fix the error, not to make the code carry on regardless of the error.

Comment: That's right. The solution is to fix the error. I also added fixed code.

Comment: The addition of `try/catch` with `console.log` makes the code worse. When an exception is thrown due to a coding bug, you *want* the control-flow to be interrupted, because otherwise your program will carry on working with data which (given an error occurred) is almost certain to be incorrect.

Comment: It depends on the whole work flow. Some code requires to run next code even if there's an error. Sometimes, try/catch makes the code worse and sometimes it's smarter. I just hoped this code would be helpful to understand how to run next function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `for (y in maincourse)` use a `forEach` loop as here. The `for in` loop returns an item after all iterations causing your code to break.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<li><a href="#" onclick="startersOnly()" >starter</a></li>
  <div class="dessert">Dessert</div>
  <div class="main_course">Main Course</div>
  
<script> 
function hideDesserts(){
    var desserts = document.querySelectorAll('.dessert');
   console.log(desserts)
    desserts.forEach((d) => {
      d.style.display = "none";
    });
}
function hideMainCourse() {
    var maincourse = document.querySelectorAll('.main_course');
   console.log(maincourse);
   maincourse.forEach((m) => {
      m.style.display="none";
    });
}
function startersOnly() {
    hideMainCourse();
   hideDesserts();
                }
</script>
</body>
```